# AlertDialog in Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to create a alert dialog in a live wallpaper basically asking people to rate..they can skip it here's what I have...but it's not showing up..it works in my webview apps, I'm using livewallpapercreator.com to make the wallpapers, I know you can add in the rating dialog to wallpapers because I've seen it done.

```
    public class SBLiveWallpaper extends WallpaperService  {

    AlertDialog alert;
    public int n=0;
    int state;

    public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME="LiveWallpaperPrefs";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {    
        super.onCreate();


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.setMessage("Please Rate Our App 5 Stars! :)")
                  .setCancelable(false)
                  .setPositiveButton("RATE NOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                           dialog.cancel();
                           startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=") ) );     


                      }
                  })
                  .setNegativeButton("Skip", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();

                      }
                  });
   alert = builder.create();
          alert.show(); 







        }
```

Comment: Isn't a `WallpaperService` a _Service_?

Comment: no idea, the question is how do I get the dialog to pop up when they goto view the wallpaper? right now it's not coming up,

Answer (score 0):

This wont come in running live wallpaper. You should do it in preference screen.

Answer (score 0):

Because the WallpaperService is a service, it can no show the dialog directly: it's unable to add  window!

So I try another way to show the `dialog:start` an activity with the Flag "`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`".

And it works finally.